# Error - invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I'm writing inline assembly code in my program. I wrote the below code and compiled the source file, named 'context.c'. But compiler consistently shows this error message.

```
 context.c:42:2: error:
 invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter
    __asm__ __volatile__(
    ^
```

I searched every article that has same error message as me, and I read inline assembly manual very carefully. But I can't find the fault code. Please help!

```
    void _os_restore_context(addr_t sp){
    __asm__ __volatile__(     //line 42
            "movl %0, %%esp             \n\t"
            "popl %%edi                 \n\t"
            "popl %%esi                 \n\t
            "popl %%ebp                 \n\t
            "addl $4, %%esp #pass esp   \n\t
            "popl %%ebx                 \n\t
            "popl %%edx                 \n\t
            "popl %%ecx                 \n\t
            "popl %%eax                 \n\t
            "popl %eflags               \n\t
            "addl $4, %%esp #pass eip   \n\t
            "popl %%ebp                 \n\t
            "ret                        \n\t
            :: "m" (sp) : "%eax"
        );
    }
```

Comment: Which compiler is it?

Comment: @kichik I solved this problem. See my answer. I used gcc.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem. The reason is eflags register. eflags and eip register has special purpose, so user program normally cannot access to it.

To give you more information, this code is part of small operating system, made for learning os. This os, named EOS(educational operation system), has hardware emulator source code in other section, and eflags register are defined as register variable in that section, written in assembly language. So, I'm advised to replace %eflags to _eflags, which is the name of register variable. After that, the error goes out.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Its not clear how you solved the problem. Can you post the code so we can see how it was solved in the code?